# Does VB.NET support virtual events?

Tags: vb.net, events, compiler-construction

In continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714893/how-virtual-events-work-in-c).
Does VB.NET supports virtual events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Does VB support the CLR notion of a virtual event

No.  This is something we've looked into supporting but did not meet our current bar in the given language cycle.

### Does VB support the idea of a hierarchy which customizes events

Yes.  You can use the Custom event syntax to allow for hierarchy controlled eventing.

```
MustInherit Class Base
    Public Custom Event Event1 As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            AddEvent1(value)
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            RemoveEvent1(value)
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            RaiseEvent1(sender, e)
        End RaiseEvent

    End Event

    Protected MustOverride Sub AddEvent1(ByVal value As EventHandler)
    Protected MustOverride Sub RemoveEvent1(ByVal value As EventHandler)
    Protected MustOverride Sub RaiseEvent1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Class
```

Comment: Could you please expand your answer with code sample? (I will select you as a winner :)

Comment: When you say "we" in your answer: was that a discussion you were part of or are you quoting something?  If you're quoting, can you give a reference?

Comment: @Joel, by "we" I meant the VS Languages team. This recently came up in the context of another internal question and I had a conversation with the compiler team about the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little slow today. And AddEvent1 should call AddHandler of the Event1 ? Isn't like, er.., endless loop?

Comment: @prankster, what this does is allow the derived class to customize the behavior of adding and removing events.  They can chose to use a plain old variable or a dynamic storage mechanism or whatever.  The example would have been clearer if i made it abstract (updated)