# C#: What are virtual events and how can they be used?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, virtual

How does a virtual event work? How would you override it? How would that work? And in what cases would you do that?

Would it for example be an ok replacement for protected OnEvent methods? So that inheriting classes could just override the event and raise it directly? Or would that be wrong or just not work?

The MSDN says this about it:

> An event can be marked as a virtual event by using the virtual keyword. This enables derived classes to override the event behavior by using the override keyword. An event overriding a virtual event can also be sealed, which specifies that for derived classes it is no longer virtual.

But that didn't make me much wiser. The sealed stuff is obvious though.

***Note:*** I've seen the [How virtual events work in C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714893/how-virtual-events-work-in-c) question, but it wasn't really about how virtual events work. Rather it was how that person got the result he got from using them. Tried to figure out what virtual events were from his example and the answers, but couldn't really make sense out of it.

Comment: Article "Virtual events in C#: something went wrong" - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0453/

Comment: These [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1070) state **Do not declare event fields as virtual**. As events are not fields, I'm not sure if the "Do not declare" stipulation is meant to apply only to *field-like events* or to all events. Elsewhere it's stated **Do not declare virtual events in a base class.** so it seems the stipulation is meant to apply to all events. The reason stated is **it is unpredictable whether a subscriber to the derived event will actually be subscribing to the base class event.**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A virtual event is simply one which *can* be overridden in a derived class.

Are you happy with the concept of a virtual property, with a getter and setter which can be overridden? If so, you can think of a virtual event in exactly the same way: instead of a getter and setter, there's an "add" operation and a "remove" operation. These can be virtual, so handled polymorphically. You implement them the same way you implement any other virtual/overridden member.

Example:

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public virtual event EventHandler Foo
    {
        add
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Foo.add called");
        }
        remove
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Foo.remove called");
        }
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Foo
    {
        add
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived Foo.add called");
        }
        remove
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived Foo.remove called");
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base x = new Derived();

        x.Foo += (sender, args) => {};
    }
}
```

Note that the event itself is not responsible for what happens when it is raised - just the add/remove side. (In C#, anyway; the CLR itself has the notion of raising, but we'll ignore that for the moment.)

You may also want to read [my article on events](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html) if you're slightly hazy on the difference between an event and a delegate.

Personally I find it *very* rare that I want a virtual event.

Comment: If the parent class raises the overridden event, it would still be the same event, right? So if you had `class A` and `class A : B`, subscribers would subscribe to the same event of an object both if it was done as A or as B?

Comment: No - raising is entirely separate. If class A overrides the add/remove and doesn't call up to class B's add/remove, then class B's mechanism for raising the event was called, then none of the handlers would be called. Think of it all in terms of plain methods - the event provides add/remove which can be virtual, but doesn't specify anything about the semantics of raising the event.

Comment: So for it to work properly you would have to do base.add and base.remove or something? (If that exists...)

Comment: Thanks for nice link btw, will read it as soon as I get the chance :)

Comment: You'd use "base.Foo += value;" within your own add implementation, etc - if you definitely want to delegate to it.

Comment: "Personally I find it *very* rare that I want a virtual event". @JonSkeet: I could see why, but one case they are really helpful is mocking. When you use e.g. Moq to mock a class and want to raise some event on that class it will have to be virtual in order to raise it. Then of course you'd usually mock interfaces. This might be the most important reason why an `event` can be virtual: if an interface can declare them, it would be weird if they can't be abstract, and if they can be abstract, it would be weird they can't be virtual.

Comment: @MarioDS: Why would you want to mock the event subscription itself though? I tend to think that mocking is overused, and this sounds like one of those places. There are easy ways of checking whether an event subscription/unsubscription has occurred in most cases. I also don't see events in interfaces very often. I'm glad all this is available, but that doesn't change the fact that I find it very rare to want it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm currently working on a WinForms project, and while the .NET events system has rough edges and flaws left and right (easy to misuse), it's a natural fit on that platform. I'm not testing event (un)subscription, I'm testing what certain components do when a dependency raises an event. Moq allows you to raise events directly, but raising can only be done from the type that declares the event. You say "raising and subscription management are entirely separate" and you're right except for that very important restriction.

Comment: @MarioDS: I'm a little lost on exactly what you're testing, but if it's useful for you, fine. I'd at least be wary that you're not over-mocking something that could easily be handled with the concrete class, but obviously I can't see your code. None of this changes *my* experience which is that it's very rare for *me* to use virtual events.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, I understand that. My default way of testing (unit testing at least), and what we do at the place I work, is to supply mocks of dependencies to a component under test through DI. Do you use different strategies for unit testing? I know it's off-topic here, but I'm eager to learn, especially from people with your experience level.

Comment: @MarioDS: As you say, it's off-topic - comment threads on SO aren't meant to turn into discussions, and without very concrete details it probably wouldn't be fruitful anyway, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there an other channel you'd be willing to chat about this? Or have you published thoughts on this elsewhere?

Comment: @MarioDS: No, I don't think I've written about it elsewhere, and I don't really have time to go into it now.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that in C# a derived class is not able to fire the event purely defined in base class (no matter what modifier it has). So we either need have a new or overriding event for the derived class and in most cases an overriding one is preferred if the same event is meant to be fired.

Comment: But that can easily be resolved by creating a `protected Raise...` method in the base class and call it from the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

For `Foo` to be raised there are 2 alternatives which I find missing from the accepted answer.

```
public class Base 
{
    public virtual event EventHandler Foo;

    public void Bar()
    {
        RaiseFoo();
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseFoo()
    {
        Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    // In this case we use the base Foo as a backing store.
    public override event EventHandler Foo
    {
        add { base.Foo += value; }
        remove { base.Foo -= value; }
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Foo;

    // In this case we raise the overriden Foo.
    protected override void RaiseFoo()
    {
        Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base x = new Derived();
        x.Foo += (sender, e) => { };
        x.Bar();
        Base x2 = new Derived2();
        x2.Foo += (sender, e) => { };
        x2.Bar();
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't work:

```
public class Derived3 : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Foo
    {
        add { base.Foo += value; }
        remove { base.Foo -= value; }
    }

    protected override void RaiseFoo()
    {
        Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```