# Listen to specific events of inherited classes

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, .net-2.0

Suppose we have the following class structure:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public event EventHandler<RipeEventArgs> Ripe;
}

public class Apple:Fruit
{
    public event EventHandler<FallEventArgs> FallFromTree;
}

public class Farm
{
    List<Fruit> fruits;
}

public class Farmer
{
    private Farm myFarm;

    public Farmer()
    {
        // listen to all FallFromTree events coming from the farm
        myFarm.WHAT += AppleFallen;
    }

    public void AppleFallen(object sender, FallEventArgs e) {}
}
```

**Question**: How do I make sure that the farmer can listen to all FallFromTree events from any apple on the farm and any apple that will be created in the future?

I was thinking of bubbling events separate, but that would mean that the `Farm` should define each event that is also covered by `Apple`. The problem is that I will create a lot of different fruits with different events and it is important that some special farmer can listen to only specific events that come from the farm. So defining every new kind of event in the `Farm` doesn't seem like a solution to me.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No, I am trying to find a way in NOT creating an enormous `Farm` class.

Comment: Why not just add an enum that describes all the things that a farmer may be interested in.  Which isn't any different from the farmer having to know about specific fruit events.  But with the considerable advantage that you now only need a single event.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that is what I have at the moment, but I don't like the fact that it cannot be checked compile time if the event sent by the apple is of the correct type that the handler is expecting. But yes, you are right. That is an option.

Comment: That isn't any different from raising the wrong event.  Or forgetting to raise it.  Or forgetting to subscribe it.  Things a compiler won't catch either.  You're actually increasing the number of ways that logical errors can creep into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the `Farm` know about the `Farmer` rather than the `Farmer` know about the `Farm`.

```
public class Fruit
{
    public event EventHandler<RipeEventArgs> Ripe;
}

public class Apple:Fruit
{
    public event EventHandler<FallEventArgs> FallFromTree;
}

public class Farm
{
    List<Fruit> fruits;
    Farmer farmer;

    public Farm(Farmer farmer)
    {
        this.farmer = farmer;
    }

    public void AddFruit(Fruit fruit)
    {
        farmer.RegisterForEvents(fruit);
        fruits.Add(fruit);
    }
}

public class Farmer
{
    private Farm myFarm;

    public Farmer()
    {

    }

    public virtual void RegisterForEvents(Fruit fruit)
    {
       //Farmer decides what events it is interested in: can override in derived classes
       if(fruit is Apple)
       {
           ((Apple)fruit).FallFromTree += AppleFallen;
       }
    }

    public void AppleFallen(object sender, FallEventArgs e) {}
}
```

The `fruit is Apple` clause isn't ideal but I think the only thing you can do there is either implement double-dispatch or have different methods on `Farmer` for each type of `Fruit`.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'm going to discuss the possibilities within my team.

Comment: This could have been the perfect answer, but unfortunately we have even more requirements that can not be facilitated by this pattern. E.g. One should also be able to subscribe to all events, without knowing what those events are. But for the question I asked, this would be a correct implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the accept. On your general requirements: ultimately something is going to need to make the decision about which events the `Farmer` should subscribe to, so whilst you'll be able to perhaps hide that knowledge from the `Farmer` itself that behaviour needs to live somewhere. If that responsibility doesn't seem to fit in any of your existing objects then maybe that indicates that you need to introduce a new class fulfilling that role. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a command handler that would handle the commands. Make the apple fall is an example of command.

```
public class MakeAppleFallCommandHandler
{
    public void Execute(Apple apple)
    {
      //This method would be called whenever any apple in the farm falls

      FallFromTree(apple);
    }

    public event EventHandler<FallEventArgs> FallFromTree;
}
```

Then in the farmer class you can subscribe to `MakeAppleFallCommandHandler.FallFromTree`. This is inspired from CQRS.

Comment: Where would you leave all these commandhandlers? It does look like a nice pattern, but I don't see how this will not significantly increase the `Farm` code, since each new event needs a new CommandHandler in the Farm to subscribe to.

Comment: Your logic is such that you would have lot of code in your application anyhow. It's only the matter of one class having lot of code against many classes having some code. In the patter above, you can write a subscription manager class that contains logic of which farm subscribes to which command handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well if Farm has fruits then it can only subscribe to events from fruit.

Define a virtual event in your base class i.e Fruit, then override it in your different Fruits child classes, like for apple it would be FallFromTree.

See this more more details
[C#: What are virtual events and how can they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127851/c-what-are-virtual-events-and-how-can-they-be-used)

Comment: This will increase the `Fruit` class enormously and will also mean that any kind of fruit would know how to fall from a tree, while some fruit doesn't even grow from a tree. So, this is just a workaround for a giant farm class.

Comment: No, what I meant was the Fruit class would have a generic event called as ChildEvent. Each child would expose it, in its own way. Like apple would expose FallFromTree for ChildEvent. Other fruits, will override their own ChildEvents as according to their property. Like Fruits grown in the root would expose GrownFromRoot

Comment: But that would mean that each fruit can only have one event. And that is certainly not the case. I want them to have multiple events as well.