# Why do virtual field-like events work the way they do in C#?

Tags: c#, events, virtual

Recently I discovered that virtual events don't work as one might expect in C#.
Consider this code:

```
public abstract class MyClassBase
{
    public virtual event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClassDerived : MyClassBase
{
    public override event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}
```

Given this definition, the following code does not behave as I would expect:

```
MyClassBase obj = new MyClassDerived();
obj.MyEvent += (s, e) => { /* Never gets called */ };

// Call method on base class that raises MyEvent
obj.DoStuff();
```

I've done a bit more extensive [write-up on my blog](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2014/06/11/virtual-events-in-csharp.aspx), but suffice it to say that I found a [warning on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx) that confirms that the behavior is unexpected, but it doesn't say anything about why. Can anyone think of a reason why it is implemented that way? Was it originally a bug which is left there for backward compatibility? I would imagine that some kind of compiler warning could at least have been added.

I realize this is most likely speculation, but I'm trying to find a plausible explanation for this weird behavior.

Comment: Why, on earth, would you want to override an event definition?  I'm kind of surprised it's even allowed :/

Comment: So what happens, what do you think should happen, and why do you think that that should happen?

Comment: Just a suggestion: follow the normal capitalization conventions in your sample code. `eventargs` isn't a standard type, but `EventArgs` is. Likewise your blog post contains a type parameter `t` when `T` would be conventional. These aren't hard to fix, but they're distracting.

Comment: @Will I agree that it's extremely unlikely you would actually want this. Just for this same reason I would expect that Microsoft is not overly concerned with backward compatibility...

Comment: The workaround is explained here in the comments by Jon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127851/c-what-are-virtual-events-and-how-can-they-be-used?rq=1

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet, somewhere along the line my blog-software HTML-ified my code and somehow that changed the capitalization of the generic type parameters. I'll fix it :P

Comment: @Thorarin: Huh? It's a well known fact that MS has suffered agility from the extent it concerns itself with backward compatibility... Not sure what that meant.  Anyhow, that Skeet burn, tho.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'm not interested in the workaround, in fact, it's in my blog post. I just want to understand why Microsoft thinks it's a good idea to leave it like this :)

Comment: The C# compiler ought to generate a diagnostic for this.  But yeah, you *always* have to use the add and remove accessor for virtual events.  *Those* methods are virtual, a field cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field-like events are expanded by the compiler to something like this:

```
public abstract class MyClassBase
{
    private EventHandler _myEvent;
    public virtual event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { _myEvent += value; }
        remove { _myEvent -= value; }
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        if (_myEvent != null)
        {
            _myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

(notice how the `DoStuff` method uses the field, not the event)

So when you override the event with another field-like event, you get a new field, and the overridden event modifies the new field, instead of the one from the base class:

```
public class MyClassDerived : MyClassBase
{
    private EventHandler _myEvent;
    public override event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { _myEvent += value; }
        remove { _myEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```

So when you add a handler to an instance of `MyClassDerived`, the `_myEvent` field in `MyClassBase` isn't affected, so the `DoStuff` method sees a null handler.

Comment: Are you confident this works? I'm not getting any output (and I believe you have to change `if (MyEvent != null)` to `if (_myEvent != null)`).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, yes, it was a typo, thanks. What do you mean by "works" ? I just described what happens in the OP's example, without attempting to fix it.

Comment: Ah, disregard my comment then. I was under the impression you provided a different workaround instead of illustrating the problem. All good then :)

Comment: It certainly seems to behave like this, but that wasn't quite the *why* I was looking for. I know a new backing field is created, but this doesn't seem to be consistent with he semantics of the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: @Thorarin, why not? What would you expect the `virtual` keyword to do in this context? An event is basically a pair of add/remove accessor methods accessors; field-like events are just syntactic sugar that create the backing field and implement the accessors for you. When you declare the event as virtual, it's actually the accessor methods that are virtual. Fields can't be virtual...

Comment: I can follow that reasoning @ThomasLevesque, but it makes overriden field-like events *exactly* the same as if I had used the `new` keyword rather than `override`. Since it provides no value, if would have been better to make the syntax illegal to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Thorarin, yes, the end result is the same. There are (arguably) legitimate uses of virtual events; for instance, you might want to allow derived classes to "disable" the event, by not subscribing to the base class event. However I agree that perhaps it should be forbidden to override an event with a field-like event; it would probably be better to enforce explicit declaration of the accessors in the override, to ensure that you know what you're doing. But unfortunately it's not going to change, since it would break existing code (even though it's probably broken already...)