# Overridden event still being original value

Tags: c#, .net, overriding

I have an issue with overriding an event in C#. I want the `SubEventTest` overrided `OnMyEvent` event to replace the `EventTest`'s `OnMyEvent`. However the `OnMyEvent` on `SubEventTest` is the same as on `EventTest`, even when trying different standard values for `EventTest`'s `OnMyEvent`.

Here's some code showing my issue:

```
void Main()
{   
    SubEventTest subEventTest = new SubEventTest();
    subEventTest.Call(); // Null reference exception (should be Hello!)

    EventTest eventTest = new EventTest();
    eventTest.Call(); // Null reference exception (as expected)
}

public class EventTest
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler();
    public void Call() => OnMyEvent();
    public virtual event MyEventHandler OnMyEvent = null;
}

public class SubEventTest : EventTest
{
    public override event MyEventHandler OnMyEvent =
        delegate ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        };
}
```

The expected output is:

```
Hello!
Null reference exception
```

The actual output is:

```
Null reference exception
```

Why is this and how can I get the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How virtual events work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714893/how-virtual-events-work-in-c)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no it doesn't that I know. My overridden event is different 
from the base class', and the linked question's is not.